# Paypal MPL sdk with credit card support

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using MPL for adaptive parallel payment. It allows user to make payment using PAYPAL ID. I need to make payment via credit card as well.

Is anyone aware how can I use credit card with MPL or any alternate way for adaptive parallel payment using PAYPAL ID and CREDIT CARD both.

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You have credit option with single payment mode only..Refer

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK (Single Mode of Payment)

In terms of parallel payment using MPL. The Paypal API itself did not gave any option for Credit card payment..!

I have worked with Both SDK's MPL and PayPal-IOS-SDK. I tried to find solution for getting Credit card payment with MPL but could not make it.

Comment: Yes. But I need to make adaptive parallel payment with credit card support as well. Though I am unable to do so using MPL but It is my requirement to allow user to make payment using Credit Card too.

Comment: I have posted issue/enhancement at github..repository.

https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/issues/49